# Pathproblem in android-manifest?

Tags: android, path, android-manifest

I'm extending Application. In another test, where everything was in the same package, everything went well. Now, I do have multiple packages and the app crashes. I guess, I miss something about the path in the manifest?

```
    <application
    android:name=".MyInheritedApplication" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Any hints appreciated!

Thanx, Marcus

Comment: Is your `package`-attribute in the `manifest`-tag set correctly?

Comment: got me! didn't set it (new to java aswell). You can post an example as answer, than I can accept it, or I can look it up myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your `package`-attribute in the `manifest`-tag is set correctly.

Example

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo.android"
    ... >

</manifest
```

Every `application` has his own `name`-attribute that will use this `package` to build up its path.